# Geometry Nodes: Fonts with Overlapping Shapes Problem

Tags: geometry-nodes, text-object, font

Fonts with overlapping shapes are broken, the intersection becomes a hole, how can I fill these?

[image: Work Sans Black Font]
[image: Result of Work Sans Black Font]

[image: Jost Bold Font]
[image: Result of Jost Bold Font]

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288548/how-to-boolean-union-closed-2d-curves-within-same-bezier-object-with-geometry-no/288610#288610

Comment: It would be nice if you attached the font… https://i.imgur.com/9GvNEHw.png

Comment: If these are Google [variable fonts](https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/introducing_type/introducing_variable_fonts), Blender is not handling those, inside or outside Geometry Nodes, as far as I can see. They can be converted to paths in Inkscape, and exported as .svg.. but I guess that might not be much help

Comment: Maybe Google would be interested in the fact their clever optimization is failing in some software. Maybe they're already aware, maybe not.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I fixed the fonts afterwards using FontForge to "remove overlaps", but Blender can easily do the remove overlap itself optionally. I was wondering if someone was aware this is a bug and if they're working to fix it or should it be reported.