# Scale (Asymmetric) curve that is not identical on the sides by given amount in mm using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, extrude, mathematics

Scale (Asymmetric) curve that is not identical on the sides by given amount in mm using geometry nodes

**Example:**

I'm trying to **create a 2mm outer wall thickness around a curve object using geometry nodes** (I'm trying to make it procedural so the wall thickness could be any number and make it 3D printable).

Something like this.

[image: img0]

My thoughts where to use the **scale elements** or **extrude node with the edge option** but as you can see from the **2.0mm measuring line (see red arrows)** the distance changes all around the object just using the scale elements node.

[image: img1]

I also tried the extrude node and that also didn't work see issue circled in **red**.

[image: img2]

I'm trying to adapt the code from
[How to boolean union closed 2D curves within same bezier object with geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288548/how-to-boolean-union-closed-2d-curves-within-same-bezier-object-with-geometry-no)

See Attached Blender File:

[image]

Note:  I was thinking if I captured each normal and extrude outward by 2mm but that's basically the extrude node.