How can I merge overlapping faces converted from a text string in geometry nodes, to avoid Z-fighting issues during rendering?
I'm using Geometry Nodes to create a string shaped plane. Here is the node setup and viewport:

The english letter "X" is correct, but the intersections of the Greek letters are empty, so I added the node Index:

The letter "ψ" seems to be correct, but after rendering, the Z-fighting effect appears, and the intersection of the letter "φ" still empty:

How can the overlapping planes of the letters be merged in Geometry Nodes?
I have tried Join Geometry and Mesh Boolean, it does not work.

You can use an external software (such as Font Forge) to correct the font file. I don't see a simple way to merge these faces.

The problem here is the font, how it was created. To be working correctly, the font designer should have made only an outer contour curve for the ψ and for the φ an outer contour and inner contour for the "hole", but unfortunately it is designed as if he took a pencil and drew a single line crossing itself for φ, while he drew two lines, a U and a | crossing each other for the ψ. That is the way the vector graphics of the font are made, you cannot do anything about it other than rebuilding it manually or using a different font which was designed differently.

Arial and Calibri for example do not have these problems, but in Calibri for example the φ is the variant ϕ (both variants exist in the font, like in Arial, but they are switched in the code).

@GordonBrinkmann In Blender yes, but according to my memories Font Forge offers 1-click fix for some of this kind of issues.

Changing the font does solve the problem, thank you.
BTW Blender's Mesh Boolean union should be able to merge overlapping planes.

@Lutzi Sure, there are ways to correct fonts, but I thought this was about how to do it in Blender and even better procedurally in Geometry Nodes. And especially when you want this setup to work in general, with interchangeable strings and fonts it might be tedious to repair everything.

@user174030 Not really, booleans are meaned to be used on manifold geometry.

@GordonBrinkmann I agree but I don't see a simple fix in Blender sadly

Just as @Lutzi said, Mesh Boolean or the Boolean modifier are used for manifold geometry, although there are sometimes exceptipns where they work on non-manifold geometry as well.

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288548/

@quellenform "Blender Sushi Guy" wrote an answer there suggesting it works for text, unfortunately both solutions there don't work in a case a single stroke (and so a single spline) overlaps self like in letter  "φ".

@MarkusvonBroady Ah, all right, those are two different use cases after all. Thank you for looking at this in detail!

I suggest the following:


Move the points of the curves along their normals by a small amount (e.g. $0.00001$).
Fill the resulting curves with Fill Curve. Do the same with the original curves.
Then send a raycast from the center of each edge to the original mesh.
Delete those edges in the original mesh whose raycast did not hit.
Convert the remaining edges into curves and fill these curves again.
Add the result to the original mesh.

This technique can of course be refined, but for your use case it should work well.
(Blender 4.1.1+)

Nice! I was considering raycasting myself… I think you should check if the scale for the normal offset should be flipped as I do, otherwise some characters may fail? For example the micro/mu "μ" character is offset in the other way, but in case of that character there is no overlap anyway... Try "Ћ" however! To be fair, my solution fails for "І" but simply increasing subdiv to 3 helps. Also my solution fails for very elaborate 'glyphs' denoting the lack of a glyph in the font. Also your solution has overlapping faces.

I expected this to be much faster than mine, but you have a slow "Fill Curve" because you don't separate into groups... But when I do, I don't get an improvement: https://imgur.com/YdboDsz - any idea why? I had to do it this way: https://i.imgur.com/NgYXNpG.png - now it's much faster than my solution. Now that I have an answer to compare I might try to optimize mine as well :D


In Blender and a lot of other software, curve filling works by filling the space that is wrapped by an odd number of curves. This is why you get undesired holes, but this is also why you get desired holes in QROPADB...
You can make an alternate filling by wrapping your curves in another curve. Now areas that were surrounded by an even number of curves are surrounded by one more, so it's an odd number, so they get filled. And vice-versa, odd becomes even, so what used to be filled no longer is. This also means the area between the original outer curve, and the added wrapping curve is now filled - the "background" of your glyphs (letters).
Delete the points in the same place as the original wrapping curve. This should remove the "background". You may want to fine-tune this technique for complicated glyphs - in my case it worked, because I processed curves independently as intances.
Now join the alternating fillings and you got rid of the holes - unfortunately both desired and undesired.
If you offset the curve by its normal, you will see that the pairs of splines that produce strokes move towards each-other or away from each-other, thinning or thickening it. I calculate if the normals should be flipped to ensure consistency in this behavior, then offset slightly along the normal and see if a face area shrank or grew - this is how I discriminate the strokes. The technique fails for long segments, so I subdivide generously… Normally I would only subdivide the long segments and maybe even restored simpler topology at the end of the process, but this is an educational website so I prefer simplicity over performance.
I tested entire Greek alphabet:
ΑαΒβΓγΔ
δΕεΖζΗη
ΘθΙιΚκΛ
λΜμΝνΞξ
ΟοΠπΡρΣ
σςΤτΥυΦ
φΧχΨψΩω



